# how to get friends of friends in pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating a friendship model schema

So here is the table structure

```
--PostgreSQL 9.6
--'\\' is a delimiter


create table user_list(
    id bigserial primary key,
    first_name text not null,
    last_name text,
    avatar_url text
);


create table friendship (
    id bigserial primary key,
    user_id bigint not null,
    friend_user_id bigint not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_friend1
      FOREIGN KEY(user_id) 
      REFERENCES user_list(id),
      
     CONSTRAINT fk_friend2
      FOREIGN KEY(user_id) 
      REFERENCES user_list(id)
);
```

and with some records

```
insert into user_list(id,first_name,last_name,avatar_url) values(1,'Sunny',null,null),(2,'Dev',null,null),(3,'Ram',null,null),(4,'Prinka',null,null),
(5,'Neha',null,null);

insert into friendship(id,user_id,friend_user_id) values(1,1,3),(2,1,2),(3,2,3),(4,2,5),(5,5,1);
```

So friendship table maintains the relations. If user1 is friend of user2 we will insert a record in friendship table (user1,user2).

This represents user1 is friend of user2 and vice-versa.

So by searching friendship of user2, user1 should be returned.

query to get friends of a user (this works fine)

```
-- get frieds of user
SELECT distinct(u.id) as friend_id,u.first_name FROM friendship AS f , user_list AS u WHERE 
CASE WHEN f.user_id = 1 THEN f.friend_user_id = u.id WHEN
f.friend_user_id = 1 THEN F.user_id = u.id END;
```

Now if i want to get the friends of friends of a user, i am trying this (nested query)

-- get frieds of friends (mutual friends) of a user

```
SELECT distinct(t.friend_id) as friend_id,t.first_name FROM 
(SELECT distinct(u.id) as friend_id,u.first_name FROM friendship AS f , user_list AS u WHERE 
CASE WHEN f.user_id = 1 THEN f.friend_user_id = u.id WHEN
f.friend_user_id = 1 THEN F.user_id = u.id END) as t,friendship as f2
where 

CASE WHEN f2.user_id = t.friend_id THEN f2.friend_user_id = t.friend_id WHEN
f2.friend_user_id = t.friend_id THEN f2.user_id = t.friend_id END;
```

even i tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT u3.friend_user_id FROM friendship u1
   JOIN friendship u2 ON u1.friend_user_id = u2.user_id
   JOIN friendship u3 ON u2.friend_user_id = u3.user_id
   WHERE u1.user_id = 1;
```

but both queries are not working. Any help on this.

and is there any other way to get friends of user an optimized way?

Here is the online pgsql tool, to try this

https://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done via a `UNION` and some `case when`, however I would recommend to always store 2 records in the friendship table, if user 1 is a friend of user 2 there should be records `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`.

```
select distinct case when f1.friend_user_id = f2.user_id then f2.friend_user_id
    when f1.friend_user_id = f2.friend_user_id then f2.user_id 
from friendship f1
left join friendship f2
    on f1.friend_user_id = f2.user_id
    or f1.friend_user_id = f2.friend_user_id
where f1.user_id = 1
UNION
select distinct case when f1.user_id = f2.user_id then f2.friend_user_id
    when f1.user_id = f2.friend_user_id then f2.user_id 
from friendship f1
left join friendship f2
    on f1.user_id = f2.user_id
    or f1.user_id = f2.friend_user_id
where f1.friend_user_id = 1;
```

This query can include also direct friends, because a friend of a friend could be also a direct friend.

### Explanation

The query has two parts, let's take part 1:

```
select distinct case when f1.friend_user_id = f2.user_id then f2.friend_user_id
    when f1.friend_user_id = f2.friend_user_id then f2.user_id 
from friendship f1
left join friendship f2
    on f1.friend_user_id = f2.user_id
    or f1.friend_user_id = f2.friend_user_id
where f1.user_id = 1
```

This will get all friendships f1 where user 1 asked other users to be there friend, i.e. (1,2) ,(1,3) but not (5,1). Then we are joining friendship table again, referenced f2, to get friends of friends. either the friend of a friend is joined by (f1.friend_user_id = f2.user_id) or by (f1.friend_user_id = f2.user_id). This would get you (2,5).

Part 2 works the same way, just starting with users that asked user 1 to be friend, i.e. (5,1) and takes it from where.

Again, the whole query could be massively simplified if always both entries would be represent, so (1,2) and (2,1).

Comment: can u explain the query?

Comment: Added explanation

Answer (score 0):

Below recursive cte should do the work for you

```
with recursive cte as 
(
select  ul.id, fd.friend_user_id from friendship fd 
 join user_list ul on ul.id=fd.user_id 
 where ul.id = 1
union all 
select ul.id, fd.friend_user_id from friendship fd 
 join cte on cte.friend_user_id = fd.user_id 
  join user_list ul on ul.id=fd.user_id 
where  fd.friend_user_id <>1
)
select distinct friend_user_id from cte
```

you can read more about recursive cte [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html).

recursive cte can go into infinite loop, make sure you add condition to avoid this like i added **fd.friend_user_id <>1**.